# How to have a common method to perform same action with two different instances of user objects?

Tags: java, object, methods

Here is how the code I am working on is currently looking like:

```
Class A {
   boolean someVariable;
   String  anotherVariable;
   //getters and setters
}

Class B {
   boolean someVariable;
   String  anotherVariable;
   //getters and setters
}

Class LetsSayMainClass {
   //init instances for A and B class
   performThis(a);
   performThis(b);

private boolean performThis(Object obj) {
     if (obj instanceof A)
        //assign a variable with the value of obj type casting to A
     else if (obj instanceof B)
        //assign a variable with the value of obj type casting to B

     if (obj.getSomeVariable)
       //Do Something
     if (obj.anotherVariable.isEmpty())
       //Do Something

   }
}
```

The Classes `A` and `B` have common variables and methods over which I would like to perform some checks. I cannot alter these classes to have a common implementable interface and factory to instantiate better. So, at this point, as the checks to be done are common for both of these classes, I am trying to use a single instance in the `performThis` method to avoid code repetition.

I cannot do something like this in the `performThis` method

```
private boolean performThis(Object obj) {
     if (obj instanceof A)
        obj = (A) obj;
     else if (obj instanceof B)
        obj = (B) obj;
     if (obj.getSomeVariable)
       //Do Something
     if (obj.anotherVariable.isEmpty())
       //Do Something

   }
```

The if conditions using the variables would throw error as they would still see the `obj` as an instance of `Object` than of either `A` or `B`.

I could have two different methods to take care of this issue. But, ts there a way to avoid the code repetition? Something I could use with the existing setup?

Comment: Why rely on an `Object` and `instanceof` (yuk!)? Can't you just overload `performThis`? That's not really "repetition" as they're distinct classes.

Comment: Even if i use the overload concept, the if conditions I am using in `performThis` cannot differentiate between the two classes unless if i repeat the code, right? 

```
if (obj.getSomeVariable) -- this obj has to be of the type A at one point and then of the type B at another point
```

Comment: If you're trying to keep DRY, you may be taking it too far. It appears you're depending on two distinct types and simply because they share a member of the same name and type you try to merge code. Are these actually different types or is there a relationship you're not defining? In any case, you can't change them so you're stuck and, IMHO, I would not use the existing setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably wouldn't do this but, if you insist on having no repetition, one thing you can do is join the types as a proxy.

```
class AorB {
  A a;
  B b;

  public AorB(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof A) {
      a = (A) o;
    } else if (o instanceof B) {
      b = (B) o;
    } else {
      // throw something?
    }
  }

  public boolean getSomeVariable() {
    return isA()
      ? a.someVariable
      : b.someVariable;
  }

  public String getAnotherVariable() {
    return isA()
      ? a.anotherVariable
      : b.anotherVariable;
  }

  public boolean isA() {
    return b == null;
  }

  // rest
}
```

That would allow you to define `performThis` like so:

```
 private boolean performThis(Object obj) {
     AorB aOrB = new AorB(obj);      
     if (aOrB.getSomeVariable())
       System.out.println(aOrB.getAnotherVariable());
     if (!aOrB.getAnotherVariable().isEmpty())
       System.out.println(aOrB.getAnotherVariable());
     return aOrB.isA();
 }
```

And use it like so:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    a.someVariable = true;
    a.anotherVariable = "This is an A";
    B b = new B();
    b.someVariable = true;
    b.anotherVariable = "This is a B";
    LetsSayMainClass lsmc = new LetsSayMainClass();
    lsmc.performThis(a); // prints "This is an A" 2x
    lsmc.performThis(b); // prints "This is a B" 2x
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chief :) Yes, I agree with you earlier comments. As I cannot update those classes, I cannot be too concerned about DRY. I have something similar to your answer in place and it works fine. Thanks again